# Have bricks been invented in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

There are lots of varied structures in Star Wars - some are made of metal, some from concrete, some adobe, etc. But there seems to be a distinct lack of bricks.

Were bricks ever invented in the Star Wars universe? If so, are there any examples of them being used?

Comment: Would you count [this](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/2/23/First_Jedi_Temple.png/revision/latest?cb=20161211110024), or do you specifically mean fired-clay rectangular bricks, bonded with a mortar?

Comment: I'm referring to rectangular bricks with mortar. I'd consider those houses stone.

Comment: Not sure why this question is downvoted. While a bit mundane, it's a perfectly valid question imho.

Comment: @Loki - I downvoted because asking if something like shaping clay or stone and gluing it together, something typically at the same technology level as farming, basic pottery, and quickly hammered out when you grasp the idea of *a wall*, is too complex a concept for a very far-future soft sci-fi fantasy setting, is just a bit daft, or at least deliberately ignoring context for bad humor.

Comment: @Radhil To a certain extent I agree and that's why I said it's a mundane question, but there have been other (somewhat also obvious) questions recently eg on the status of medical tech during the death of Padme and so on. A very advanced civilization should be able to do very complicated  tasks like that quite easily, so all questions about daily lives etc should be trivial.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, in Theed on Naboo.

This scene shows the Queen being arrested, bricks are clearly used in the background.[image]

Comment: not definitive - could be concrete pressed with a brick shaped form: http://www.brickform.com/Textures/About-Our-Textures/ (lol - I kid - your answer has my upvote)

Comment: not definitive - the prequels don't exist. they never happened.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, large stone bricks were used in the construction of Canto Bight Stables

[image]

> *The stables were made of brick and stone, with stalls that were more
> like jail cells—small and dark, with barred gates that opened
> electronically.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Canto Bight](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canto_Bight_(novella_collection))</sup></sub>

---

There was brickwork at Jedha Spaceport

> The ground changed beneath his feet, the old stonework streets of the
> city **giving way to the brickwork of the spaceport’s promenade.** Ahead
> of him, not so far away now, was Baze. Ahead of him, not so far away
> now, was their goal.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Guardians of the Whills](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Whills_(novel))</sup></sub>